# How to render an ember-data date in a template

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to print a date attr in my handlebars template. But the output is empty. How do I render it?

My Model:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
    type: DS.attr('string'),
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    summary: DS.attr('string'),
    body: DS.attr('string'),
    date: DS.attr('date')
});


App.Post.FIXTURES = [
    {id:1, type:"news", title:"Some", summary:"Lorem ", date:new Date()}, 
    {id:2, type:"gallery", title:"Some", summary:"Lorem", date:new Date()}
];
```

My handlebars template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="posts">
    {{#each post in controller}}
        {{post.date}}: {{post.type}}- {{post.title}}
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with example of your problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use a new Date() in the Fixture itself, you should be using an ISOstring or something similar.
Remember the transform for Date looks for a string to come from the persistence layer (in your case a Fixture) and then will convert it to the Date object from your string.

So, set your date in the Fixture to be "2013-02-07T16:44:57.000Z" or something similar i.e. "2013-02-07T16:44:57" should work too.

Comment: Any idea how I can format the output of the date? `{{post.date}}` now echoes: `Thu Feb 07 2013 17:44:57 GMT+0100 (CET)`. Let's say I want something like: dd-mm-yyyy.

Comment: You can have a handlebars helper, that can format it the way you like.
Instead of {{post.date}} you would do {{parseDate post.date}} and parseDate is your helper that you define.

Comment: I don't believe this is true anymore. The FixtureAdapter does not use a serializer and expects the fixtures to be normalized. https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/fixture_adapter.js#L31